# Issues when creating bot with Language Understanding Intelligent Service Template

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

After I input App ID and password, I selected Language Understanding Intelligent Service Template and clicked create button, it's showing loading page and then get stuck on this step forever.

Can someone advise why this happened?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience! We're currently looking into this issue and will update when there is more information.

Comment: Hello, this issue should be resolved. Please check it again